# Cannot select destination for bootloader during installation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have a windows 10 system that I would like to install Ubuntu onto. I have created two partitions, one for `/boot` and the other for `/`. During installation with Mantic Manticor I see the option to install the bootloader to `/dev/sda` is disabled:

[image: partitioning screen showing inability to select desired destination]

This prevents me from proceeding with install. How should I proceed? What prevents selection of my desired destination?

Comment: You haven’t given us enough information to be sure but you seem to already have an EFI partition (sda1). If this is a UEFI installation then you don’t need the one you manually created (sda3). Are you really unable to proceed or are you unable to proceed in the way you expected by specifying the boot loader location? Let us know if you are doing a legacy or UEFI installation